# BigQuery Nested Table - if nested record do not exist?

Tags: google-bigquery

Have a straight question.

If the record is is null in SQL we use **WHERE XXX is null**

How about if nested records do not exist at all, like this:
[image]

`WHERE XXX is empty???`

What I would like to do? - Need to filter out records which do not have anything in OrderLines

Comment: Have fixed the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nested record is an array - to check if array is empty - I would use

```
WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH(OrderLines) = 0
```

Comment: This was my logic )) `AND TO_JSON_STRING(ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT ol.* FROM unnest(OrderLines) as ol)) != '[]'`